# What I do wrong with LOAD DATA INFILE and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to add some records to existing table with UPDATE ON DUPLICATE.
My Table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts` (
  `accName` varchar(31) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `accId` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `twitchName` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `challenge` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


INSERT INTO `accounts` (`accName`, `accId`, `twitchName`, `challenge`) VALUES
('titi_love', 1, '', 1),
('oli1304', 2, '', 0),
('zeella', 3, '', 4),
('Snapfire', 4, '', 0),
('ncsbert', 5, 'ncsbert', 1),
('litmusdragon', 6, '', 1),
('Tsenk6a1', 7, '', 0),
('Azimuth69', 8, '', 0);

ALTER TABLE `accounts`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`accName`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `accName` (`accName`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `accId` (`accId`);

ALTER TABLE `accounts`
  MODIFY `accId` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=9;
```

I try it hard but can't find solution.
Existing records in `accounts` can't change `accId` and `accName` i need only add new records and if `accName` already exist then update filed `twitchName` and `challenge`
I have [csv file](http://37.233.101.14/phpfusion/test.csv) and I try to add it like that:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp LIKE accounts;
LOAD DATA INFILE '/www/phpfusion/test.csv' INTO TABLE tmp FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (`accName`, `twitchName`, `challenge`);
SHOW COLUMNS FROM tmp;
INSERT INTO `accounts` SELECT `accName`, `twitchName`, `challenge` FROM tmp ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `accName`= VALUES(`accName`), `twitchName` = VALUES(`twitchName`), `challenge` = VALUES(`challenge`);
```

or like that:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp LIKE accounts;
LOAD DATA INFILE '/www/phpfusion/test.csv' INTO TABLE tmp FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (`accName`, `twitchName`, `challenge`);
SHOW COLUMNS FROM tmp;
INSERT INTO `accounts` (`accName`, `twitchName`, `challenge`) SELECT (`accName`,`twitchName`, `challenge`) FROM tmp ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `accounts`.`twitchName` = tmp.twitchName, `accounts`.`challenge` = tmp.challenge;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct!

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp LIKE accounts;  
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/www/phpfusion/test.csv' INTO TABLE tmp FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (`accName`, `twitchName`, `challenge`);  
INSERT INTO `accounts` (`accName`, `twitchName`, `challenge`) SELECT `accName`,`twitchName`, `challenge` FROM tmp ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `accounts`.`twitchName` = tmp.twitchName, `accounts`.`challenge` = tmp.challenge;  
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmp;
```